# looking for symbol to denote - opposite of ~, or something equal to K(A)<<1>>K(A) for K(A)

Tags: notation

My teacher wrote   K(A) ~ 1, (called it almost equal to 1) i need the opposite, such as K(A) is far from 1.
I wrote   K(A) << 1 >> K(A),  but it definitely looks redundant.

Alternatively I could write   1<<K(A)>>1 (is this better math notation-wise?) but that still looks redundant.

Do we have a symbol that denotes far from (and can be either larger or smaller than) 1?

Comment: What is $K(A)$ ?...

Comment: $K(A)\not\approx 1$ or $K(A)\not\sim 1$, maybe?

Comment: @Jean Marie its just a symbol, but if you want to know it is the called the condition number for the matrix A, and tells how numerical stabile/unstabile a Image matrix is when debluring an image from (i think) SVD (it is hard and complicated to accually find the best value in debluring),   so when K(A)~1, it is numerical stabile, and K(A) far from 1, it is numerical unstable.   it is the relationship between the larges and smalles Singular value's K(A)=a_1/a_r . i hope it helps

Comment: You find in the special case of the condition number the double superior sysmbol $K(A)>>1$

Comment: @Jean Marie are you saying i should use (A)>>1, and does that mean it can only be larger than, and not less than, thx

Comment: Yes, in the case of the condition number, it's what we need.